# Language specific characters in json

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, tomcat

I need to send some language specific characters in my json to a local tomcat server I am running. Everytime it encounters those characters, it says "400 - Request is syntactically incorrect", as expected

Any work arounds? Also, I don't want it to support certain specific languages, but keep it generic and support all languages that the browser sending the request supports.

Supporting Spring MVC at the backend, which will process the json input

Sample:

```
абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя=один
```

Controller code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/services", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public ResponseEntity<Response1> executeService(
                @RequestBody Request1 request) {
    //controller code
    }
```

Json request:

```
{
  "serviceName":"abc",
  "input":{
    "text":"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя=один"
  }
}
```

P.S. Json is valid for English characters, controller works normally if I send normal English characters, and correct output is displayed in that case.

Check comments for specific errors faced

Comment: Looks like your not using `UTF-8` encoding end-to-end.

Comment: And read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Sorry, but how to add encoding at client side, the person who sends the request via a REST Client, say as a browser extension?

Comment: Same was as anywhere else, set the correct headers.

Comment: Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
I am setting this. Gives 415: Unsupported MediaType error for this

Comment: `абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя=один` should be `{"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя" : "один"}`

Comment: `415: Unsupported MediaType` is not indicating an encoding problem. What is the `Content-type` header you set, what does the server method accept?

Comment: server expects "application/json"
content type, as mentioned, is "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 2):

This isn't valid JSON. Valid JSON would look like this:

```
{"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя" : "один"}
```

The other usual culprit is the charset or encoding. JavaScript uses Unicode for strings and any JSON framework worth its salt will use UTF-8 encoding when preparing the data for the wire. So unless you're trying to do everything yourself (not using any framework) or you're tampering with the headers and especially the `Content-Type` header, this should work out of the box.

If these two suggestions don't solve your problem, you'll have to show us your code.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear, the string would be something like 
{ "name" : "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя=один" }

Comment: That's valid JSON. Did you check whether the request looks correct on the wire? Most browsers today allow you to look at the data being sent and received.

Comment: With charset=utf-8 header, 415 error is displayed
Without that, request is syntactically incorrect and doesn't look fine on the wire either

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990717/spring-mvc-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616319/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-spring-mvc-jdbc-te